# Latex Template for Journal of Neural Engineering

Tags: overleaf, journal-publishing

Does anyone know how I can find a latex template for the Journal of Neural Engineering?
I could not find any neither on their website nor by searching on google.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's as such no ``LaTeX`` template for Journal of Neural Engineering. As the journal is published by IOP Science, you should use [this template](https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/ioplatexguidelines.zip). The [IOP Science ``LaTeX`` guidelines](https://www.math.drexel.edu/~rperline/snapshots/latex/IOPLaTeXGuidelines.pdf) mentions that once your document is accepted then the `.tex` code will be converted to the appropriate format for the journal concerned.

Comment: In addition to what Tanvir said, if you're using Overleaf (based on your tag) we do have that same .zip file from IOP already available in our templates gallery: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/author-guidelines-for-publishing-to-iop-journals-in-latex/dbftskdgszdz